# Can I break the columns of a table to new lines with CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have this table:

```html
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Title 1</td>
    <td>Title 2</td>
    <td>Title 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Description 1</td>
    <td>Description 2</td>
    <td>Description 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Button 1</td>
    <td>Button 2</td>
    <td>Button 3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and it is displayed in this way

[image: table display]

Now I would like to break the columns with CSS so that the table is displayed in this way

[image: new table display]

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Do you have any control over the markup?

Comment: With CSS it is impossible. As Shaggy said, you need to modify your html or use JavaScript to split your table.

Comment: Via CSS , you could use display:contents and flex to reorder elements http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/WjeEpV  .... but i believe only FF undertsnds display:contents at this time

Comment: Nice solution GCyrillus! Never heard about `display: contents`, but as you said it only works in firefox.

Answer (score 0):

No, You have to make 3 separate tables for that.

Answer (score -1):

You might have to create 3 tables